# Let $M:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3 :x^2+y^2=2z^2,z>0\}$ and $f(x,y,z):=(x+y+z)^2e^{-z}, \forall(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$. Find...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $M:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3 :x^2+y^2=2z^2,z>0\}$ and

$f(x,y,z):=(x+y+z)^2e^{-z}, \forall(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$.

i) Prove that $f$ has a absolute maximum and minimum in $M$.

ii) Prove that $M$ is a differentiable variety in $\mathbb R^3$ and find the absolute and relative extremes of $f$ in $M$.

I didn't know how to do start with i) so I tried jumping straight into ii) and I had real trouble when solving the equations defined by deriving with respect to $x,y,z$ of:
$\Phi=(x+y+z)^2e^{-z}-\lambda(x^2+y^2-2z^2)$.

I tried starting with the case $\lambda=0$ but I'm unable to finish it.

Edit: I only need help with the case $\lambda=0, $ I managed to get the case $\lambda \neq 0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum value of $f$ is zero.

This should be easy enough to show as $(x+y+z)^2 \ge 0$ and $e^{-z} > 0$ and $(1,-1, 1)$ is in $M$

As for the maximum:

My best idea is to chose some value for $z = n.$  Find the maximal value with this restriction.  Let $g(n)$ be this maximum.

Find the $n$ that maximizes $g.$

I suppose we can be more abstract with it.

For some $n$ there is an upper bound on $f$ when $(x,y,z) \in M$ and $z > n$

Let $M' = \{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2 = 2z^2, 0\le z\le n\}$

On the domain $M'$ we have a continuous function on a compact (closed and bounded) domain.  Which must achieve a maximum value, by the extreme value theorem.

The show that there is a  point on $M'$ where $f(x,y,z)$ is greater than the upper bound you found earlier.